# how to create div dynamically in JSP using for each loop in such a way that I can toggle it to hide and show

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I am creating an webpage(in JSP) where I am loading multiple row dynamically in div from the `Map<?> collections`.
For Example
`displayName` collection has `Name1, Name2, Name3` etc and each name has their own attribute list like `attributeList1, attributeList2, attributeList3` etc.

Now I don't have any problem of showing this list in a div like below.

> Name1 | att1 | att2 | att3 | att4 etc.All the att1,att2,att3 are
>   values from attributeList1
>
> Name2 | att1 | att2 | att3 | att4 etc All the att1,att2,att3 are
>   values from attributeList2
>
> Name3 | att1 |3att2 | att3 | att4 etc All the att1,att2,att3 are
>   values from attributeList3
>
> Name4 | att1 |3att2 | att3 | att4 etc All the att1,att2,att3 are
>   values from attributeList4
>
> Name5 | att1 |3att2 | att3 | att4 etc All the att1,att2,att3 are
>   values from attributeList5
>
> Name6 | att1 |3att2 | att3 | att4 etc All the att1,att2,att3 are
>   values from attributeList6

Now I want to make Name1 as the parent  of Name2 and Name3 so that I want to put a link on "Name" (first column) and on clicking the link Name1, Name2 and name3 rows will be show or hide. Similarly on clicking Name4, Name5 and Name6 will be show or hide.
Basically I want to group these rows on the fly using their parent child relationship and showing the the child in a div so that I can apply Jquery to toggle them. Here for Name2 and Name3 ,  I have Name1 as there parentId as a property.

Please help me.

Comment: what you have tried for this? have you start rendering div using jquery or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide and show any element, for that you can use JQuery.
Example:

So here what we are doing, we can select any "class" or "id" of any element and can apply hide and show functions easily.

Note: Don't forget to add JQuery library in your header.

I hope this will help you.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to render you all your `div` so that we can find the child of the parent div. There should be some attribute to identify the child div.

Here i have created divs in which `parent div` have name attribute which the first column value in your code, and all its child have name attribute whose value is combination of the parent name attribute and constant string `_child` append at the end.

```
<div id="name1Par" name="name1" onclick="hideDiv(this)" style="cursor: pointer;"> Name1 Parent Div </div>
<div name="name1_child"> Name2 Child of Name1</div>
<div name="name1_child">Name3 Child of Name1</div>
<div id="name4Par" name="name4" onclick="hideDiv(this)" style="cursor: pointer;">Name4 Parent div</div>
<div name="name4_child">Name5 Child of Name4</div>
<div name="name4_child">Name6 Child of Name4</div>
```

Here is JavaScript function using JQuery to toggle your child div :

```
function hideDiv(ele)
{
    var divName = $(ele).attr("name");
    var chilDivName = divName+"_child";
    $("[name="+chilDivName+"]").toggle(); 
}
```

Some how you need to render your div or rows so that you will find childs of parent.

If you are using table than add `onclick` event on first column that call `hideDiv()` function and toggle your child row as show above.

[Here is JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5n7yF/4/)

Comment: Thanks Yagnesh... its really helpfull and its working perfect except in IE. In I am getting an error like this                                                           Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; .......
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 2
Char: 29694
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/javadashboard/resources/javascript/jquery-2.1.1.min.js;jsessionid=3930BF3F9D28D03BFF0AABBC3C9CD705

Comment: Its may be due to name attribute not support in IE. Which version of IE are you using ?